# What does $[n]$ mean?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, notation

I have to prove that every subset of the partial order $B_n=(P([n], \subset)$ has a supremum and infimum. I'm not asking for the solution, I just want to know what $[n]$ means.

Comment: In discrete math and combinatorics, people usually write $[n] = \{1, 2,3, \ldots, n\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the context that $[n]$ should be a set, the notation usually means either $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ or $\{0,1,\dots,n-1\}$, depending on the convention. The first might be more common, but the second is nice because then $[n]$ corresponds to $n$ as a [cardinal number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_number).

However, if you're working with simplicial sets, then $[n]$ might mean $\{0,1,2,\dots,n\}$ since it's supposed to correspond to the vertices of an $n$-dimensional simplex.